# How to configure IIS for MSSQL windows authentication in mvc 5 application

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a Microsoft.Net MVC5 application which is deployed on a server and is working with IIS. Server uses static I.P. and hence the application is accessible from anywhere(internet).

Concern is around the database access, which is a MSSQL database, for now application is working with it using a SQL Authentication. Infra team is asking us to move away from sql authentication and to work with Windows Authentication and we are not sure how to configure IIS or IIS_IUSRS access to the database. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Follow the below post that will help to you:
[Window authentication in sql server and asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469816/window-authentication-in-sql-server-and-asp-net)

Comment: Change SQL Server authentication mode (mixed mode). Create a new user. Edit the WebSite ApplicationPool Identity and enter previously created user, Open SQL Server and add the previously added user with datareader and datawriter roles on your Database.